# Parsing - Top down / First & Follow

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I have this Grammer where i am trying to find First and Follow sets. I am not sure if i am doing it right since my follow sets never include the first of R

Grammar

```
E --> TP
P --> +TP | ε
T --> FQ
Q --> FQ | ε
F --> (E)R | iR
R --> *R | ε
```

First Sets -

```
First(E) = First(T) = First(F) = { (, i }
First(P) = { +, ε }
First(Q) = First(F) = { (, i }   // not needed i dont think
First(R) = { *, ε }
```

Follow Sets -

```
Follow(E) = { $, ) }
Follow(P) = Follow(E) = { $, ) }
Follow(T) = First(P) -{ε} + Follow(E) = {+, $, ) }
Follow(Q) = Follow(T) = { +, $, ) }
Follow(F) = First(Q)-{ε} + Follow(T) + First(F) = { +, (, ) , $, i }
Follow(R) = Follow(F) = { +, (, ) , $, i }
```

I never get to first(R) in the follow set so im not sure what to think. However, i dont think its possible either. Am i correct with my first and follow sets or is my understanding somewhat wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R doesn't start any production, First(R) wouldn't come into play (except if/when you start from R).  So you SHOULDN'T reach it from anything else.